# How to split long regular expression rules to multiple lines in Python

Tags: python, regex

Is this actually doable? I have some very long regex pattern rules that are hard to understand because they don't fit into the screen at once. Example:

```
test = re.compile(
    '(?P<full_path>.+):\d+:\s+warning:\s+Member\s+(?P<member_name>.+)\s+\((?P<member_type>%s)\) of (class|group|namespace)\s+(?P<class_name>.+)\s+is not documented'
        % (self.__MEMBER_TYPES),
    re.IGNORECASE)
```

Backslash or triple quotes won't work.

Comment: `re.VERBOSE` [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957846/python-regex-meaning/7958248#7958248)

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: I had to give +1 for re.DEBUG alone, that will make my life so much easier in the future!

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I upvoted your answer in behind the link because in the end I still ended up using it even though it required more editing (had to make sure every whitespace is marked correctly).

Comment: btw, [@N3dst4's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8006551/how-to-split-long-regular-expression-rules-to-multiple-lines-in-python/8006611#8006611) provides a nicer alternative to `(?x)` by enabling syntax highlighting. Also you could use `[ ]` or `\ ` to escape a space.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian and Makis: What is **re.DEBUG** ????

Comment: @eyquem: [`re.DEBUG`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/re.py#l126) means ['dump pattern after compilation'](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/sre_parse.py#l681).

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can split your regex pattern by quoting each segment. No backslashes needed.

```
test = re.compile(
    ('(?P<full_path>.+):\d+:\s+warning:\s+Member'
     '\s+(?P<member_name>.+)\s+\((?P<member_type>%s)\) '
     'of (class|group|namespace)\s+(?P<class_name>.+)'
     '\s+is not documented'
    ) % (self.__MEMBER_TYPES),
    re.IGNORECASE)
```

You can also use the raw string flag `'r'` and you'll have to put it before each segment.

See the docs: [String literal concatenation](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation)

Answer (score 29):

From the docs, [String literal concatenation](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation):

> Multiple adjacent string literals (delimited by whitespace), possibly using different quoting conventions, are allowed, and their meaning is the same as their concatenation. Thus, `"hello" 'world'` is equivalent to `"helloworld"`. This feature can be used to reduce the number of backslashes needed, to split long strings conveniently across long lines, or even to add comments to parts of strings, for example:
>
> ```
> re.compile("[A-Za-z_]"       # letter or underscore
>            "[A-Za-z0-9_]*"   # letter, digit or underscore
>           )
> ```
>
> Note that this feature is defined at the syntactical level, but implemented at compile time. The ‘+’ operator must be used to concatenate string expressions at run time. Also note that literal concatenation can use different quoting styles for each component (even mixing raw strings and triple quoted strings).

Answer (score 21):

Use the `re.X` or `re.VERBOSE` flag. Besides saving quotes, this method is also portable on other regex implementations such as Perl.

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.X):

> `re.X`
>
> `re.VERBOSE`
>
> This flag allows you to write regular expressions that look nicer and are more readable by allowing you to visually separate logical sections of the pattern and add comments. Whitespace within the pattern is ignored, except when in a character class or when preceded by an unescaped backslash. When a line contains a `#` that is not in a character class and is not preceded by an unescaped backslash, all characters from the leftmost such `#` through the end of the line are ignored.
>
> This means that the two following regular expression objects that match a decimal number are functionally equal:
>
> ```
> a = re.compile(r"""\d +  # the integral part
>                    \.    # the decimal point
>                    \d *  # some fractional digits""", re.X)
> b = re.compile(r"\d+\.\d*")
> ```
>
> Corresponds to the inline flag `(?x)`.

---

*P.S. [The OP said they ended up using this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8006551/3) in a previous edit to the question.*

Answer (score 8):

Personally, I don't use `re.VERBOSE` because I don't like to escape the blank spaces and I don't want to put **'\s'** instead of blank spaces when **'\s'** isn't required.
The more the symbols in a regex pattern are precise relatively to the characters sequences that must be catched, the faster the regex object acts. I nearly never use **'\s'**

.

To avoid `re.VERBOSE`, you can do as it has been already said:

```
test = re.compile(
'(?P<full_path>.+)'
':\d+:\s+warning:\s+Member\s+' # comment
'(?P<member_name>.+)'
'\s+\('
'(?P<member_type>%s)' # comment
'\) of '
'(class|group|namespace)'
#      ^^^^^^ underlining something to point out
'\s+'
'(?P<class_name>.+)'
#      vvv overlining something important too
'\s+is not documented'\
% (self.__MEMBER_TYPES),

re.IGNORECASE)
```

Pushing the strings to the left gives a lot of space to write comments.

.

But this manner isn't so good when the pattern is very long because it isn't possible to write

```
test = re.compile(
'(?P<full_path>.+)'
':\d+:\s+warning:\s+Member\s+' # comment
'(?P<member_name>.+)'
'\s+\('
'(?P<member_type>%s)' % (self.__MEMBER_TYPES)  # !!!!!! INCORRECT SYNTAX !!!!!!!
'\) of '
'(class|group|namespace)'
#      ^^^^^^ underlining something to point out
'\s+'
'(?P<class_name>.+)'
#      vvv overlining something important too
'\s+is not documented',

re.IGNORECASE)
```

then in case the pattern is very long, the number of lines between
the part  `% (self.__MEMBER_TYPES)` at the end
and the string `'(?P<member_type>%s)'` to which it is applied
can be big and we loose the easiness in reading the pattern.

.

That's why I like to use a tuple to write a very long pattern:

```
pat = ''.join((
'(?P<full_path>.+)',
# you can put a comment here, you see: a very very very long comment
':\d+:\s+warning:\s+Member\s+',
'(?P<member_name>.+)',
'\s+\(',
'(?P<member_type>%s)' % (self.__MEMBER_TYPES), # comment here
'\) of ',
# comment here
'(class|group|namespace)',
#       ^^^^^^ underlining something to point out
'\s+',
'(?P<class_name>.+)',
#      vvv overlining something important too
'\s+is not documented'))
```

.

This manner allows to define the pattern as a function:

```
def pat(x):

    return ''.join((\
'(?P<full_path>.+)',
# you can put a comment here, you see: a very very very long comment
':\d+:\s+warning:\s+Member\s+',
'(?P<member_name>.+)',
'\s+\(',
'(?P<member_type>%s)' % x , # comment here
'\) of ',
# comment here
'(class|group|namespace)',
#       ^^^^^^ underlining something to point out
'\s+',
'(?P<class_name>.+)',
#      vvv overlining something important too
'\s+is not documented'))

test = re.compile(pat(self.__MEMBER_TYPES), re.IGNORECASE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Either use string concatenation like in [naeg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8006576/4518341) or use `re.VERBOSE`/`re.X`, but be careful this option will ignore whitespace and comments. You have some spaces in your regex, so those would be ignored and you need to either escape them or use `\s`

So e.g.

```
test = re.compile(
    """
        (?P<full_path>.+):\d+: # some comment
        \s+warning:\s+Member\s+(?P<member_name>.+) #another comment
        \s+\((?P<member_type>%s)\)\ of\ (class|group|namespace)\s+
        (?P<class_name>.+)\s+is\ not\ documented
    """ % (self.__MEMBER_TYPES),
    re.IGNORECASE | re.X)
```

Comment: I tried this first, but it didn't work. Maybe I made some error, but my initial thought was that Python included the white space. At least when I print something in that style, whitespaces are printed as well.

Answer (score 1):

The Python compiler will automatically concatenate adjacent string literals. So one way you can do this is to break up your regular expression into multiple strings, one on each line, and let the Python compiler recombine them. It doesn't matter what whitespace you have between the strings, so you can have line breaks and even leading spaces to align the fragments meaningfully.