# python split regex into multiple lines

Tags: python, regex

Just a simple question. Lets say i have a very long regex.

```
regex = "(foo|foo|foo|foo|bar|bar|bar)"
```

Now i want to split this regex into multiple lines. I tried

```
regex = "(foo|foo|foo|foo|\
          bar|bar|bar)"
```

but this doesnt seems to work. I get different outputs. Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, then i get an invalid syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do it like this

```
regex = "(foo|foo|foo|foo" \
            "|bar|bar|bar)"
```

Comment: This is the same solution as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/8006611/3832970